# There's no resource in my dll. But why the .rdata part in my dll is so big?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I'm trying to make my dll smaller because it is a little bigger.
I used dumpbin.Here's the result.
Summary

```
   19000 .data
  195000 .rdata
   21000 .reloc
  2C3000 .text
```

I think this a problem because I think the .rdata part contains resources of a dll file. But I didn't add any resource to my dll.

Comment: Why is that a problem? Do you have any const globals? You provided very little information.

Comment: You should really add some more information, probably what you are working with, and some hint; otherwise this is nothing than guessing.

Comment: I think this a problem because I think the .rdata part contains resources of a dll file. But I didn't add any resource to my dll.

Comment: I'm trying to make my dll smaller because it is a little bigger.

Comment: could be surveilance program. Whenever I compile a program on msvs2015community on windows10, it contacts somewhere and I unplug ethernet cable and it gives network error while what I wrote is just a=1+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.rdata` is not only for resources (if by resources you meant Windows resources like strings, icons, manifests, etc.). `.rdata` also contains any constant data. Consider a dll that would have only this:

```
static const int j[2000];

__declspec(dllexport) const int* foo()
{
    return j;
}
```

`j` would actually be placed in `.rdata` (if you play around with the size you'll notice how the changes are visible in the `size of raw data` line in the output of `dumpbin /SECTION:.rdata`. So inspect your program for large constant variables as well.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rudolfs' suggestion regarding source inspection, you can probably disassemble the DLL with ResourceHacker or similar utility, and verify whether the `.rdata` size is justified or not.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it.